# Find GPS is ready to give good Location after enable the GPS in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I facing a problem when a user enable the GPS and instantly want a location by location manager that time GPS is not ready to give best accurate result because it take sometime to get stable but i don't know when it will stable and ready to give accurate result.
Please help me to find accurate location after start the GPS from device .

Comment: You can get locations normally and check the accuracy of the Location object.. For example, accuracy < 16 meters is pretty accurate.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that time i didn't get the location because instantly GPS is not stable and ready to give location.

Comment: Use [requestLocationUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates) and you'll get the location as a callback when it's available. You can then cancel the updates, if you do not require constant updates.

Comment: Can u share with me any example or link so that i can understand easily ..  thanks in advanced